# Specified color looks different when saved as pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am plotting something with a hatched area. However, when saving it as a .pdf the color is different from what I specified it. In the console it is displayed correctly and also when saving as a .png file it shows the correct color. I am wondering if this has been observed before and if someone knows a workaround / fix for this or if I am doing something wrong.

This is what I want the picture to look like:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the pdf:

[image]

As you can see the hatching works fine for all peaks except the red one. In the pdf the hatching is gray instead of red. Also the colors in the pdf seem to be more transparent than in the png.
I am using matplotlib version 3.2.2.
For reproduction here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

def gauss(x,mu,sigma,a):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))

x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)


data1 = gauss(x,6.5,0.5,10)
data2 = gauss(x,3,0.8,15)
data3 = gauss(x,5,0.2,12)
data4 = gauss(x,8,0.4,11)
data = data1 + data2 + data3 + data4

fs = 20
ls=20
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

plt.plot(x,data,'k.',mfc='none',label='Data')
plt.plot(x,data,'r')
plt.fill(x,data1,'gold',ec='darkgoldenrod',label='1')
plt.fill(x,data2,'crimson',ec='darkred',hatch='//',alpha=0.5,label='2')
plt.fill(x,data3,'mediumslateblue',ec='b',hatch='\\\\' , alpha=0.5,label='3')
plt.fill(x,data4,'limegreen',ec='darkgreen',hatch='++',alpha=0.5,label='4')
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=fs)
plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=fs)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', width=1.5, length=5, direction='in', pad=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', width=1., length=3.5, direction='in', pad=15)

handles, labels= ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles[0], handles[1], handles[2], handles[3], handles[4] =  handles[1], handles[2],handles[3], handles[4],handles[0]
labels[0], labels[1], labels[2], labels[3], labels[4] = labels[1], labels[2], labels[3], labels[4], labels[0]
ax.legend(handles,labels,loc='upper left',fontsize=15)

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
tmp = list(ax.get_yticklabels())
ax.set_yticklabels(['' for _ in tmp])
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
plt.xlim(10,0)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=ls)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Correct_colors.png')
plt.savefig('Incorrect_colors.pdf')
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Without the spectrum of your data, no one can reproduce your plot. pls kindly use some synthetic data, and do the plot for data privacy. You can just use Gaussian function to model the curve.

Comment: Well with just about any data you could reproduce the issue, really. I mean I dont really care about the plotted data/curve but the color. Anyways, I changed it for your convenience.

Comment: Hi, @Nils, I have run your code, but I cant reproduce the same as yours.

Comment: Hmm, could you tell me what matplotlib version you are using?

Comment: I am using 3.2.2

Comment: Have you ever tried viewing pdf on Chrome? some pdf viewer renders differently. My foxit reader have different render effect from Chrome.

Comment: Well that's weird.. I tested it on two different computers with different environments which both have version 3.2.2 and I was able to reproduce it. I cant really imagine that another library is interfering there somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: @ted930511 you're absolutely right.. in Chrome it does look the same.. That's crazy I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: Okay, so the issue lies within my pdf reader... I'd never have thought of that.. Thanks a lot :)